# Using a MIDI-Out port that has been physically plugged up

Tags: midi, digital-piano

A little while ago, I purchased a [Huntington KB61 electronic piano](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0052BFLB0).
At the moment, it cannot hook it up to my computer as a MIDI input keyboard.

When I purchased this, it wasn't such a big deal, but now I'm really wishing it had this capability. Since I am rather low on cash at the moment, I was wondering if there were some way I could set this up with my piano, rather than buying a whole new one.
Here is a picture of the back of the KB61:
[image: KB61-Midi-out]

As you can see, it has a place for MIDI-OUT, but it is "filled up".

Is there any way that I can change this?

**Does anyone know any way I can set up the MIDI-OUT port for my keyboard?**

Comment: I don't know if this will help any: http://makezine.com/2009/09/10/convert-an-old-keyboard-to-midi/

Comment: MIDI capability would require a whole extra set of electronics inside they keyboard -- this would not be as simple as soldering a connector to a circuit board and cutting a hole. That Italian hobbyist video is exactly what you'd need to do.

Answer (score 3):

I know nothing about Huntington keyboards. It looks to me like the back panel was cut and printed for a MIDI-out port but that your particular model of Huntington simply does not have MIDI capability at all.

At any rate, this is a US $70 keyboard, and undoubtedly its capabilities are extremely limited. I doubt that the keys are of good quality, and I also doubt if they can output MIDI velocity.

If you want to work with a MIDI keyboard, you should spend more money on a more capable product. While you are at it, look for one with a MIDI-over-USB port so you can simply plug it into your computer, without the need for purchasing a separate MIDI-to-USB interface device.

[Here is a link](http://www.guitarcenter.com/Portable-Keyboards-Portable---Arranger-Keyboards,MIDI-USB-Connections-Both.gc?ipp=25) to several inexpensive models of Casio and Yamaha keyboards that have MIDI In and MIDI Out as well as MIDI-over-USB.